# How to check whether one number range from one file is the subset of other number range from other file?

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

I'm trying to find out whether range1 numbers [both columns a and b] are the subset or lying between range2's columns [both columns b and c].

range1

```
 a       b
15       20
 8       10
37       44
32       37
```

range2

```
 a       b       c
    chr1    6       12
    chr2    13      21
    chr3    31      35
    chr4    36      45
```

output:

```
    a       b       c
chr1    6       12       8       10
chr2    13      21       15      20
chr4    36      45       37      44
```

I have tried to learn from this code [which is working if we wanted to check if a single number is lying in a specific range], therefore I tried modifying the same for two both numbers. But did not work, I'm feeling I'm not able to read the second file properly.

I wanted to compare range1[a] with range2[b] and range1[b] with range2[c]. One to all comparison.

For example in the first run: the first row of range-1 with all other rows of range-2. But range1[a] should be compared only with range2[b]  and similarly, range1[b] should be compared only with range2[c]. Based on this only I have written a criteria :

```
lbs[i] && lbsf1[j] <= ubs[i] && ubsf1[j] >= lbs[i] && ubsf1[j] <= ubs[i]

r1[a] r2[b] r1[b] r2[c]
15 > 6      20 < 12     False
15 > 13     20 < 21     True
15 > 31     20 < 35     False
15 > 36     20 < 45     False
```

Code: [[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359361/check-number-in-another-file-if-in-range-using-shell-script) but little modified]

```
    #!/bin/bash

awk -F'\t' '
# 1st pass (fileB): read the lower and upper range bounds
FNR==NR { lbs[++count] = $2+0; ubs[count] = $3+0; next }
# 2nd pass (fileA): check each line against all ranges.
{ lbsf1[++countf1] = $1+0; ubsf1[countf1] = $2+0; next }
{
        for(i=1;i<=count;++i)
                {
                        for(j=1;j<=countf1;++j)
                        if (lbsf1[j] >= lbs[i] && lbsf1[j] <= ubs[i] && ubsf1[j] >= lbs[i] && ubsf1[j] <= ubs[i])
                                { print lbs[i]"\t"ubs[i]"\t"lbsf1[j]"\t"ubsf1[j] ; next }
                }
}
' range2 range1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hello. First point, into the second block `{...}` (without condition) we have a `next` statement at the end. So the third block (with loops) is never executed.

Comment: Do you have a good result ?

Comment: yes I got the resu;t

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69104341/how-to-check-whether-one-number-range-from-one-file-is-the-subset-of-other-numbe/69105292#69105292

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because cross-posted https://stackoverflow.com/q/69104341/4023950